# Sqoop Command field termination line termination is not working from hue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to transfer RDBMS table to Hadoop using sqoop command.
When I run the command from Bitvise SSH Client command line, it worked properly.

When I run same command from Oozie workflow editor from hue, data transfered successfully. All the data is transfered in first field not in appropriate fields.
Can anyone help me.

```
import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:BISTAGE/BISTAGE@128.1.100.97:1521:Ilasuat --table DOC_TYPE_MASTER --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --target-dir hdfs://128.1.26.28:8020/user/hive/warehouse/ins_staging.db/doc_type_master -m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I have removed single quotes from \t and \n and data is is transferred appropriately.